# How to check whether a ViewData variable expired from javascript or Jquery side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I am retrieving a variable value from ViewData to a javascript variable as follows.

```
  var selectedList= <%= ViewData["selectedList"] %>;
```

and by nature ViewData expired after some time.  I am looking for a way to check whether this variable has expired from the JavaScript side. I am trying to do this without using  a session .

Comment: This viewdata will be placed in a view page [aspx/ascx/cshtml], in this case, what will be condition in which the viewdata will expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewData Value gets expired after page load completes. You can keep ViewData value into Javascript Global variable that you can use for further processing.